# Nested Fn::ImportValue in Fn::Sub not working for SAM template

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

**Description:**
I am trying to define Serverless API resource. But having trouble in defining location of swagger specification file using function ImportValue.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**
I am not able to define `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource having nested function `ImportValue` in Location. I have tried following three ways, none of them work.

Note: Stack parameters are defined properly and export value from other stack exists. Not showing them here for brevity reason.

```
ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-API
        StageName: !Ref ApiGatewayStageName
        DefinitionBody:
          'Fn::Transform':
            Name: 'AWS::Include'
            Parameters:
              Location:
                Fn::Sub:
                - s3://${BucketName}/${SwaggerSpecificationS3Key}
                - BucketName:
                    Fn::ImportValue:
                      !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-dist-bucket-${AWS::Region}" 



ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-API
        StageName: !Ref ApiGatewayStageName
        DefinitionBody:
          'Fn::Transform':
            Name: 'AWS::Include'
            Parameters:
              Location:
                Fn::Sub:
                - s3://${BucketName}/${SwaggerSpecificationS3Key}
                - BucketName:
                    !ImportValue 'dev-dist-bucket-us-east-1' 



ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-API
        StageName: !Ref ApiGatewayStageName
        DefinitionBody:
          'Fn::Transform':
            Name: 'AWS::Include'
            Parameters:
              Location:
                Fn::Sub:
                - s3://${BucketName}/${SwaggerSpecificationS3Key}
                - BucketName:
                    Fn::ImportValue: 'dev-dist-bucket-us-east-1'
```

Cloudformation shows following error.

> FAILED - The value of parameter Location under transform Include must
>   resolve to a string, number, boolean or a list of any of these.

However, if I do not use `ImportValue` it works with a nested `Fn::Sub`

```
ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
        Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-API
        StageName: !Ref ApiGatewayStageName
        DefinitionBody:
          'Fn::Transform':
            Name: 'AWS::Include'
            Parameters:
              Location:
                Fn::Sub:
                - s3://${BucketName}/${SwaggerSpecificationS3Key}
                - BucketName:
                    Fn::Sub: dist-bucket-${EnvironmentName}-${AWS::Region}
```

Is it because of Fn::Transform or AWS::Include?

Comment: I've got the same problem.. See also https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/372 (you created it ^_^)

Comment: Any news on this? The github issue referenced is closed...

Comment: Any particular reason why your first examples reference `dev-dist-bucket-us-east-1` (environment first) and the example that works is `dist-bucket-${EnvironmentName}-${AWS::Region}` (environment after)?

Comment: @tyron it just happened to be the way my stack output variable and distribution bucket name is defined. Example that works is because of the fact, I have no `Fn::Import` under `Fn::Sub` or vice versa.

Comment: @Ludo no news mate. SAM guys closed it by saying it is not specific to them but  cloudformation/Include fn.

Comment: @NomanYaqub I was just trying to understand if you have both `dev-dist-bucket-us-east-1` and `dist-bucket-dev-us-east-1` buckets created.